# В колайдеры попадает уничтоженный обьект

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вопрос. Я дестрою обьект и вызываю событие, на  событие подписан такой код(он находится на другом обьекте)

```
var coliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(gameObject.transform.position, col.radius);
```

И у меня как то в колайдеры попадает удаленный обьект

Comment: Объект уничтожается только в следующем кадре, а не в текущем. Это глобальная механика для Unity, просто надо учитывать это поведение.

Comment: и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Можно проверять, уничтожен он или нет. https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-check-if-a-gameobject-is-being-destroyed.1030849/

Comment: @aepot а можно юзануть New WaitForEndOfFrame()?

Comment: Не знаю, не пробовал. Если речь про корутину, то почему бы и нет.